# reference the current category being used in the category.php page

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, post-thumbnails

I have this code in my category.php file

```
            <?php query_posts( array('post_type'=>'featured' )); 

            $featured = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page'=>1, 'tax_query'=> array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'fever'
            )
        )));

                while ( $featured->have_posts()) : $featured->the_post();
                unisphere_get_post_image('normal-slider');?>
                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This code works, but what I need is where it says 'terms' => 'fever' to instead reference whatever the current category being used in the category.php page would be. I need it to work this way so that my featured image changes out with the current category that being used by the page category.php at that moment.

// Got the answer I needed. Here's a copy of the working code.

```
            <?php 
            $term = get_queried_object();
            query_posts( array('post_type'=>'featured' )); 

            $featured = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page'=>1, 'tax_query'=> array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $term
                        )
                    ) 
                ));

            while ( $featured->have_posts()) : $featured->the_post();
            unisphere_get_post_image('normal-slider'); ?>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Just a question...why are you using query_posts when you're also using new WP_Query?

Comment: not sure. just figuring out stuff as I go.

Comment: NP :) Here's a great reference post to read through. Very helpful! http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using get_queried_object():

```
$term = get_queried_object();
echo $term->name;
```

If you get nothing there, try this:

```
print_r($wp_query);
```

Everything you need is in the $wp_query global.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: that did the trick!